# Can we use custom component(Library Component) in State Management (ngrx) in angular

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-library

I am creating custom library in that is made by me and publish it to npm store and installing  it in different project for state management.
Is this possible to use custom library in state management ?

Comment: So... You're building a state management library but you want to know if it's possible to build a state management library?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Chris  Actually we are creating a custom component and using it in state management (ngrx) . I am trying to POST data is this possible or not.
If you know Please share example.